# Inherit styles from 2 other elements within the same container with .LESS

Tags: css, less, mixins

I'm new to .LESS and to avoid repeating the same rules for the declared elements within the same container I'd like to know if there is a cleaner way of doing it.

So far I have:

```
.outer-container {
 .inner-container1, .inner-container2 {
  padding: 0;
  margin-top: 8px;
  }
 .inner-container3 {
   background: none;
   border-top: none;
 }
}
```

What I'd like is for .inner-container1, .inner-container2 and .inner-container3 to have `font-size: 12px` without having to repeat it in each. Is that possible please?

Comment: You could make another class called inner-container or something alike and then assign the font-size to it.

Answer (score 2):

You could simply use css attribute selector.

```
div[class^="inner-container"]
```

will select all divs matching class *starting* with inner-container

More info about attribute selectors in css [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors)

```css
div[class^="inner-container"] {
    font-size: 12px;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer-container">
  <p>I'm an outsider :(</p>
  <div class="inner-container1">
    <p>Dude, i'm in </p>
  </div>
  <div class="inner-container2">
    <p>me too!!<p> 
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Maharkus basic support is there. Its the case insensitive modifier thats not supported